# Android Studio crashes (no error message)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm on x64 Windows 10 pro) I downloaded the latest version of JDK and Android Studio, wanted to learn how to build android apps, until the setup and managing SDK and AVD everything was fine, I created a new Hello World project and it started to download some stuff and it suddenly crashed, now when I start Android studio it opens normally but crashes when it finishes indexing files, there is no error message, it just closes. I tried running as administrator, created a new JAVA_HOME variable but that didn't work either. I realized every time i run AS a new file like this is created under my user directory:

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x00007ffb8c6139af, pid=2152, tid=3912
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
Problematic frame:**
C [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb39af]***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmVrJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your error. Here is my link for you. [LINK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8238246)

I think you should **delete your JDK and Android Studio.**
Recently, Android Studio program is updated and you don't need to install JDK separately. In my case, I didn't have to install JDK separately too when I installed Android Studio. And **re-install Android Studio ONLY!** Don't install JDK. Because some errors like this are often caused by a duplication of JDK file.

I want you to like my answer. **Thank you.**